# Connecting Websocket to Qt Fortune Server with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, websocket

I am trying to connect to the Qt Fortune Server Example, with this HTML/Javascript Code : http://jsfiddle.net/gr0bhrqr/

I edited this line of code:

```
websocket = new WebSocket("ws://yourDomainNameHere.org/");
```

In Chrome, I get this error in the console:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:50745/' failed: Error during
>   WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED

I also tried with Firefox - no connection. My firewall is off - the given port is free.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Qt Fortune Server example does not implement the Websocket protocol.

You can find Qt Websocket examples [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebsockets-examples.html).